# Excel lookup based upon common cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two tables with SKU and pricing data. I want to look at the SKU column and check the pricing columns for those SKUs to make sure they match. I'd like for a cell from table 2 that doesn't match the respective cell on table 1 to be highlighted yellow (so in the second table I'd expect to see price column 1 highlighted for SKU 12345).

| SKU | Price Column 1 | Price Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | $444 | $400 |
| 67890 | $200 | $125 |

| SKU | Price Column 1 | Price Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | $443 | $400 |
| 67890 | $200 | $125 |

Comment: how have you tried conditional formatting to do this?

Comment: I haven't because of the differences in rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, then you might be looking for something like this as shown in the screenshot. If so then you could try using <kbd>ISNA( )</kbd> & <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd>, alternatively if you don't have <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd> can use <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function as well.

---

[image]

---

- First select the range of cells where the <kbd>Conditional Formatting</kbd> should be applied.

---

- From <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> Under <kbd>Styles</kbd> Group --> Click On <kbd>Conditional Formatting</kbd> --> Click <kbd>New</kbd>

---

- <kbd>New Formatting Rule</kbd> Window opens --> Select the last rule <kbd>Use a formula to determine which cells to format</kbd> and enter the below formula in the edit the rule description.

---

```
=ISNA(XMATCH($E2&"|"&$F2&"|"&$G2,$A$2:$A$3&"|"&$B$2:$B$3&"|"&$C$2:$C$3))
```

---

- Click <kbd>Format</kbd> to choose preferred fill color from Fill Tab and press <kbd>Ok</kbd> twice.

---

Some working examples:

[image]

---

Note that you need to increase the range of the **lookup_array**.

---

Comment: Unfortunately the SKUs will not always be in the same row.

Comment: Yes, I know, did you try the formula yet? It would work, because it is checking all the rows using an `XMATCH()` function which returns a number for the match and error for which doesnt match.

Comment: @Chris refer the update, it works but you need to extend the range of cells for the **lookup array** in the function

Comment: Here is what I have:

=ISNA(XMATCH($J19&"|"&$L19&"|"&$M19&"|"&$N19&"|"&$O19,$A$19:$A$782&"|"&$E$19:$E$782&"|"&$F$19:$F$782&"|"&$G$19:$G$782&"|"&$H$19:$H$782))

When used, all highlighted cells have the formula applied.

Comment: Ok, go ahead, what issue did you face, as it works on my end. Do you have a excel workbook share able link so i can see, what is wrong at your end.